# Is there any Sanskrit-Greek-Latin-English dictionary available?

Tags: latin, greek, sanskrit, resource-request

Is there any Sanskrit-Greek-Latin-English dictionary [including online] available? I am so much interested in etymological study. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics SE!

Answer (score 6):

Not a single dictionary, but you could get the effect by chaining together resources. I suggest starting with Bopp's [Glossarium Sanscritum](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/) which is a Sanskrit-Latin Glossary. After a few pages of that, you will probably be convinced that for etymological study, you don't want a Sanskrit-X dictionary, you probably want a dictionary of Sanskrit with etymological notes, or an etymological dictionary with a Sanskrit index. U Texas has an online adaptation of Pokorny's [Indogermanisches etymologisches Wörterbuch](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/PokornyMaster-X.html), and through the language index you can get at a list of [Sanskrit words](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/Skt.html). There you can find various Sanskrit words, e.g. *yákr̥t* which has a link to [i̯ē̆ku̯-r̥(t-)](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P0777.html#Skt), where you'll learn that the Sanskrit word is related to Hometic Greek *ἧπαρ*, English *liver*, Latin *hepaticus*, Hittite *lissa*, Armenian *leard* and Lithuanian *yãknos*.

The [Köln Sanskrit dictionaries page](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/) will take care of many of your Sanskrit needs. The Perseus Project provides [Greek, Latin and Old Norse](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform).

Comment: Bopp’s Sanskrit dictionary from 1847 is really not going to be of any use to you. The standard work for Sanskrit etymology is Mayhofer, Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Altindoarischen.

Comment: That was my point: for etymological study, you don't want a Sanskrit-X dictionary, you want an etymological dictionary.